# Ruby YAML parsing memory leak?

Tags: json, ruby, memory-leaks, yaml

I am parsing a rather large YAML file. I wrote a script whose sole action was to parse this file into a Ruby hash. Here are the results generated by `ruby_memory_profiler`:

```
Total allocated: 731.61 MB (10417787 objects)
Total retained:  488.47 MB (5366317 objects)
...
retained memory by class
-----------------------------------
 306.88 MB  Psych::Nodes::Scalar
 107.25 MB  String
  61.09 MB  Array
...
retained objects by file
-----------------------------------
   2620244  .../ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb
   2557326  .../ruby/2.7.0/psych/tree_builder.rb
     62916  .../lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/nodes/node.rb
```

So the detail shows that almost all of the allocation is done by the psych tem.

The code basically looks something like this:

```
MemoryProfiler.report { YAML.load_file(filespec) }.pretty_print(scale_bytes: true)
```

---

Am I correct in my understanding that the 488 MB retained is a problem with the YAML parser (psych) not releasing all references to its internal data?

The data involved are simple Ruby objects -- hashes, arrays, strings, and integers. I am thinking of using JSON instead of YAML. Can anyone offer any experience doing this, and how likely it would address my memory problem? Or offer any information helping me understand, and hopefully resolve, this problem?

Comment: What is your definition of a _large YAML file_? How big is it actually in MB and LOC?

Comment: It's 2.5 million lines, and 38 MB in size.

Comment: Until the artifacts of `MemoryProfiler.report` go out of scope, why would you expect the memory profile and its artifacts to be garbage collected?

Comment: I am presuming that MemoryProfiler is intelligent enough to report correct results -- otherwise, how would it the retained objects information it provides be useful at all?